# How to animate a object's rotation on all 3 axes simultaneous?

Tags: animation, rotation, blender, axis

I have an empty which i need to be rotating on all 3 axes simultaneous.
It can be done quite easily in Blender 4 using Simulation zone and a transform modifier with values on x,y,z.
Unfortunately i  have to use Blender 3.5. I didn't find a way to convert geometry nodes action to keyframes, so i have to do it by animating keyframes. Although i do have keyframes on x,y,z when playing, the object only rotates on one axes.

I've seen a solution here[text](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r0cYUKJHX2c)
But it's quite cumbersome. Anyone knows a simpler way?
Why is rotating an object on all 3 axes simultaneous so complicated in Blender??!

i tried keyframing rotation on all 3 axes. It only rotates on one.